# Python: How to create a sequence of two-tuples

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, tuples

I am working with Django and I'm getting an error that I don't know how to fix.  I'm sure this is a newbie problem.  I have the following data structure that I thought would be "a sequence of two-tuples:"

```
CONFERENCES = (
    ( 'AE' 'AFC East' ),
    ( 'AN' 'AFC North' ),
    ( 'AS' 'AFC South' ),
    ( 'AW' 'AFC West' ),
    ( 'NE' 'NFC East' ),
    ( 'NN' 'NFC North' ),
    ( 'NS' 'NFC South' ),
    ( 'NW' 'NFC West' ),
)
```

This is referenced like this:

```
class Conference( models.Model ): 
    conference_name = models.CharField( max_length=2, choices=CONFERENCES )
```

However, Django is giving me this error after I run `python manage.py validate`:

```
gameTrackerApp.conference: "conference_name": "choices" should be a sequence of two-tuples.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well for one, you don't have commas in your inner-tuples. Each tuple in Python needs at least one comma (even one-item tuples)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing commas:

```
CONFERENCES = (
   ( 'AE', 'AFC East' ),
   ( 'AN', 'AFC North' ),
   ( 'AS', 'AFC South' ),
   ( 'AW', 'AFC West' ),
   ( 'NE', 'NFC East' ),
   ( 'NN', 'NFC North' ),
   ( 'NS', 'NFC South' ),
   ( 'NW', 'NFC West' ),
)
```